# Can't move element to end at right time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to slide images left inside a div set to hide overflows, and then remove the first image and append it to the end, so that I always have the same number of images in the list and they keep sliding left each time the function fires:

```
function xxx(){
    var first = $('.ximg:first');
    $('.ximg').animate({ left: '-=200'}, 2000, function(){ $('.ximg').css({left: '0'}); first.insertAfter($('.ximg:last'));});

}
setInterval(function(){ xxx () }, 8000);

<div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width: 400px; height: 150px;">
    <div class="ximg" style="position: relative; width: 200px; min-height:150px; background:red"></div>
    <div class="ximg" style="position: relative; width: 200px; min-height:150px; background:orange"></div>
    <div class="ximg" style="position: relative; width: 200px; min-height:150px; background:green"></div>
    <div class="ximg" style="position: relative; width: 200px; min-height:150px; background:yelow"></div>
</div>
```

But I only end up with 1 image in the  container, the second only gets added when the function fires. I know there are read made plugins to do this kind of thing but I want it simple and prefer to try and write my own even thought I am relatively new with jquery !

http://jsfiddle.net/rgct2/6/

The container is 400 wide and as each div is 200 wide, there should always be 2 divs in view, even during animation when it will show a % of the first and 3rd divs.

Comment: That's because are you removing the element, remove the `remove()`.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed remove() but it did not cure it. I suspect that it is related to the resetting of the left position to 0 is not firing at the right time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is probably to animate the width of the first element, so it doesn't require all elements to be animated.

```
function xxx() {
    var origWidth = $('.ximg:first').width();
    $('.ximg:first').animate({
        width: 0
    }, 2000, function() {$(this).insertAfter($('.ximg:last')).css({width: origWidth})});
}
```

There are also CSS problems with the elements. The parent element should have `white-space: nowrap`, so the elements are in the same line, even when they're not visible. The children elements should have `display:inline-block`, so they can be in a line (i.e. inline), and have configurable widths.

Another thing to be aware of is the space between `<div>`s. You need to make sure there is no unintentional spaces, which include newlines.

See the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rgct2/7/.

Comment: OK, I spoke too soon. Can't reduce the width of the first element as in the live situation, this div will contain other elements, so it has to be shifted left.

Comment: even if it contains other elements, reducing the width should still be okay, as long as you have the CSS set correctly, e.g. overflow, white-space.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and its working, instead of use remove, use "**detach**"

```
function xxx(){

     $('.ximg').css({left: '0'});
     $('.ximg').animate({ left: '-=200'}, 2000, function(){ });
     $('.ximg:first').detach().insertAfter( $('.ximg:last') );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added an example on jsfiddle and amended the original code with a slightly different method, but it's still not working as expected. the div wrapper should always show 2 divs, even when animating, but right now it's only showing 1.